# How to inject multiple angular services using $inject.get

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Im having problem using $inject.get in angular js..

Let say i have angular services like this

```
app.service("serviceOne", function() { 
 this.dialogAlert = function() {
  return 'Message One'
 };
});

app.service("serviceTwo", function() { 
 this.dialogAlert = function() {
  return 'Message Two'
 };
});

app.service("serviceThree", function() { 
 this.dialogAlert = function() {
  return 'Message Three'
 };
});
```

And using the factory to dynamically call dialogAlert()

```
app.factory("alertService", function($window, $injector) {
 if ($window.servicesOne) {
   return $injector.get("serviceOne");
 } else {
   return $injector.get(["serviceTwo", "serviceThree"]);
 }
});
```

With this kind of codes, it gives me "unknown provider".
Or is there any alternative solution for this?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[injector.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#get) takes only one service name as argument, array is not supported, you may want to do return array of service instances by doing `return ["serviceTwo", "serviceThree"].map($injector.get)`:-

```
app.factory("alertService", function($window, $injector) {
  var service = ["serviceOne"];
  if (!$window.servicesOne) {
   service = ["serviceTwo", "serviceThree"]; 
  }
  return service.map($injector.get); //To be consistent send back this as well as array
});
```

So with this when you inject the `alertService` it will return an array of dependecy(ies).

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, alertService) {
 //  alertService will be array of dependecies.
  console.log(alertService.map(function(itm){return itm.dialogAlert()}));
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/y7GIlM?p=preview)**

or return with a map:-

```
 app.factory("alertService", function($window, $injector) {
      var service = ["serviceOne"], 
          serviceObjs = {};

      if (!$window.servicesOne) {
       service = ["serviceTwo", "serviceThree"]; 
      }

      angular.forEach(service, function(itm){
        serviceObjs[itm] = $injector.get(itm);
       });

     return serviceObjs;
    });
```

Comment: This one is correct, but what if the method is not dialogAlert, let say, in the serviceThree its different name..  it will have errors

Comment: @AnthonyPillos That was just for example, i mentioned a console.log invoking the function. :D

Comment: the last code you give is the one im looking for... and by the way... do you think the foreach doesnt have problem if looping many services?